Quarto-Pandoc: md to latex: How to change .cell and .cell-output formatting?
I'm trying to develop a Quarto extension for an OA journal. In that context, I need to change how Pandoc formats the R code junks and their output. I know about Quarto extensions and partials. I searched for hours but cannot find the solution to my (fairly simple) problem. Please help!
I render a document to PDF and keep the MD-file as well as the TEX-file.
In the MD-file, I have:
::: {.cell}

```{.r .cell-code}
sqrt(2)
```

::: {.cell-output .cell-output-stdout}

```
[1] 1.414214
```

:::
:::

By default, this translates to the following code in the TEX-file:
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\FunctionTok{sqrt}\NormalTok{(}\DecValTok{2}\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{verbatim}
[1] 1.414214
\end{verbatim}

For my journal extension, I need to replace the "verbatim" environment by a "Verbatim" environment (capital "V"). Is there a tex-partial or another configuration file that needs to be changed for that? I just cannot find the right place.
I searched through the online documentation and the GitHub repos mentioned there.

Instead of changing the output of quarto, you could tackle this from the latex side and redefine verbatim to be the same as Verbatim:
---
title: "Proof of Concept"
author: "Your Name"
date: "2024-06-08"
format: pdf
header-includes:
 - \RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{}
---

::: {.cell}

```{.r .cell-code}
sqrt(2)
```

::: {.cell-output .cell-output-stdout}

```
[1] 1.414214
```

:::
:::

